# xpath count function

Tags: xml, xpath, count

I am trying to use XPath count function to determine how many elements are returned by following query

```
doc("courses.xml")
count(//Course[contains(Description,"Cross-listed")])
```

The following code returns 2 course elements

```
 doc("courses.xml")
//Course[contains(Description,"Cross-listed")]
```

but when I try to use the count function as above to return "2"  I get the following error.

Error on line 2 column 1 of tmpDfWgJ7.xq:
 XPST0003 XQuery syntax error in #doc("courses.xml")
count(//#:
 Unexpected token "(" beyond end of query
Static error(s) in query

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

count(doc("courses.xml") //Course[contains(Description,"Cross-listed")])

Answer (score 0):

**Use either**:

```
count(doc("courses.xml") //Course[contains(Description,"Cross-listed")])
```

**or what may be more readable**:

```
doc("courses.xml")/count(.//Course[contains(Description,"Cross-listed")])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work too. You just need to add / before count:

```
doc("courses.xml")
/count(//Course[contains(Description,"Cross-listed")])
```